# How to test API with Spring Boot Web Authentication and Postman?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm currently building a RESTful FAQ Service with Spring Boot. I'm using Spring Security for the Web Authentication so the user needs the correct password and username to see the page. This data is also connected to a MySQL Database. In this moment I'm working on a Import/Download feature for Excel files. But I actually can't test it because every time I send a GET Request in Postman I always get the login page from Spring Boot security. Is there a way to baypass this or to tell Postman to login automatically with the correct username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using permitAll it means every authenticated user, however you disabled anonymous access so that won't work.
What you want is to ignore certain URLs for this override the configure method that takes WebSecurity object and ignore the pattern.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/signup");
}
```

And remove that line from the HttpSecurity part. This will tell Spring Security to ignore this URL and don't apply any filters to them.